# 500 internal server error Azure Web App

Tags: c#, database, azure

I have created a web application, an SQL Server and an SQL Database for my web app in Microsoft Azure Platform.The SQL server is not running on a VM it is just using the SQL Database Service.

The web app was working perfectly until I inserted some data at the database. Pages which are linked with the database are not working at all. I tried to find the error at the log files and it's Error 500.0 modulename= managedpipelinehandler notification= execute_request_handler.

Do you have any idea what could I do to fix that? Is it possible for the database to disfunction cause of the server location in azure?

Comment: The 500 error response should contain much more information, try to look at that.

Comment: Which backend framework is used by your web app ? Asp.net ? Asp.net Core ?